# Analysis of overlapping regions $y_{n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Suppose we have the following inequality $$f(n,x) \leq y(n,x) \leq g(n,x)$$ (Just to emphasise this is a region in two dimensional $\Bbb{R}^{2}$ space) and $n$ is a positive even integer. Let's call the region obtained as $y_{n}$.
Then can we get the form for $\omega_{n_{0}}$, where $$\omega_{n_{0}} = \cap_{n =\frac{n_{0}}{2}}^{n_{0}} y_{n}$$
Say $f(n,x) = A^{2n} + n x A^{n} B; g(n,x) = -3A^{2n} + nxA^{n}B$, where $|A|<1, B $ is $\mathcal{0}(1)$ real quantities,
$n_{0}$ is an even integer!
Can we get information about $\omega_{n_{0}}$, which can  help us understand the region $\omega_{n_{0}}$ better?

Perhaps these can be done using a computer but I would like to see if this can be done analytically!

Comment: Is $y$ a number or a function?

Comment: Oh yes, function!

Comment: What are the arguments for $y$ on the left and right sides then? Is it $n, x$ there as well?

Comment: Thanks, that was a  typo!